# jquery dynamically loaded tab with a script inside

Tags: jquery, tabs, dynamic, loaded

JQuery UI let us have tabs loaded dynamically:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

My question is: if the dynamically loaded tab needs scripts, how do I need to write them?

Should I use a $(document).ready method again? like that:

Tab1.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       alert("hello");
    });
</script>
<p>Tab Content</p>
```

----------------- end of tab1.html -----------------

In this example the alert shows each time the tab is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your tabs, you need to set `cache:true` like this:

```
$("#tabsWrap").tabs({
   ...
   cache: true 
   ...
});
```

Comment: This is excellent! it certainly look obvious once you know it.